# Why files under bin folder cannot be found?

Tags: directory, bin

I inside my httpdocs(www), i created a folder called "bin", i put an "test.html" just to display "Hello Stackoverflow", but when I go access the page, i.e http://domain.com/bin/test.html, it says Page Cannot Be Found. But when I move the file to test folder, it display what it should be. Why?

Comment: Basically the bin folder is usually for executables, and you don't usually want to give the anonymous users permission to execute stuff on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the default config, as part of generally good security practice won't be configured to do anything that isnt normal (like doing stuff other than executing stuff in the bin directory, or stuff that wouldnt normally happen in the base directory).  In general, I'd say you should be trying to fit in with this, rather than going against the grain.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly permissions.

```
chmod 755 /Path/To/Bin/
chmod 644 /Path/To/Bin/test.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the evident "check permissions" answer and asuming you are using Apache server you may need to add a .htaccess file with the right permissions in each folder.

Look for .httaccess in other folders and remember to use ls -a ( file begining with dot are hidden by default -a = All )

By the way, it may be a bad practice to put html files in a binary folder.